# jQuery class doesn't add on changing the option of a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

I have attributes (color, size) and their units(black,blue || 32cm,42cm).
I want when selecting the color from the select box it should open the first unit's select box (black, blue) and when to click on size then it should open the 2nd select box (32cm,42cm). I've done almost everything but not been able to get the expected result.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   //attr selector with options of units

   $('.attr-selector').change(function(){
     var data = $(this).children().attr('data-link');
     $('.unit-select').removeClass('active');
     $('#'+data).addClass('active');

   });


});
```

```css
  .unit-select{
   display: none;
  }
  .unit-select.active{
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
        <!--*** ATTR ****-->
        <div class="col-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control attr-selector">
              <option>Select</option>
              <option value="" data-link="1"><b>Color</b></option>
                <option value="" data-link="2"><b>Size</b></option>
              <option value="" data-link="3"><b>Space</b></option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
  <!--***Units Of attr 1***-->
        <div class="col-2 unit-select" id="1">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option value=""><b>Red</b></option>
                <option value="" ><b>Green</b></option>
              <option value=""><b>Blue</b></option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

  <!--***Units Of attr 2***-->
        <div class="col-2 unit-select" id="2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option value=""><b>32</b></option>
                <option value="" ><b>40</b></option>
              <option value=""><b>42</b></option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
   <!--***Units Of attr 3***-->
        <div class="col-2 unit-select" id="3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option value=""><b>Color</b></option>
                <option value="" ><b>Size</b></option>
              <option value=""><b>Space</b></option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

Comment: you shouldn't start your ids with numbers fyi

Comment: so what should be the code??

Comment: thats not the issue I was just pointing that out, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: okay, & I got my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target only the selected option and its corresponding data-attr.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   //attr selector with options of units

   $('.attr-selector').change(function(){
     var data = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-link');
     $('.unit-select').removeClass('active');
     $('#'+data).addClass('active');

   });


});
```

```css
  .unit-select{
   display: none;
  }
  .unit-select.active{
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
        <!--*** ATTR ****-->
        <div class="col-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control attr-selector">
              <option>Select</option>
              <option value="" data-link="1"><b>Color</b></option>
                <option value="" data-link="2"><b>Size</b></option>
              <option value="" data-link="3"><b>Space</b></option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
  <!--***Units Of attr 1***-->
        <div class="col-2 unit-select" id="1">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option value=""><b>Red</b></option>
                <option value="" ><b>Green</b></option>
              <option value=""><b>Blue</b></option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

  <!--***Units Of attr 2***-->
        <div class="col-2 unit-select" id="2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option value=""><b>32</b></option>
                <option value="" ><b>40</b></option>
              <option value=""><b>42</b></option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
   <!--***Units Of attr 3***-->
        <div class="col-2 unit-select" id="3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option value=""><b>Color</b></option>
                <option value="" ><b>Size</b></option>
              <option value=""><b>Space</b></option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

Comment: One `.find()` can change the entire code.. Thanks. Thank you so much